# ActionController::RoutingError uninitialized constant within autocomplete field (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, routes

Here are my routes:

```
match '/goods_ins/autocomplete/autocomplete_supplier_suppliername', :controller => 'goods_ins'

match '/goods_ins/autocomplete/autocomplete_partcode_partcode', :controller => 'goods_ins'

get 'autocomplete_partcode_partcode', :controller => 'goods_ins'

get 'autocomplete_supplier_suppliername', :controller => 'goods_ins'
```

and this is my auto complete field:

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label "Supplier Name" %><br />
<%=f.autocomplete_field :suppliername, :autocomplete => autocomplete_supplier_suppliername_path %>
</div>
```

when i type something in to the field, i get this error in terminal:

ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant GoodsIns):

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a GoodsIns controller and model? The route is looking for the controller for the GoodsIn model. The error seems to suggest this is undefined?

If you could provide more info about what you are trying to do that would be great!

Comment: yes i have both of those, i have a form of which two of the fields need to be autocomplete enabled with data from two different tables. the fields are suppliername and partcode. the tables are called supplier and partcode. i've followed this documentation: https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete